# Drupal 8 fresh install, and following the hello world module tutorial, ended up getting: The response failed verification so will not be processed

Tags: ajax, drupal, drupal-8

So i followed the Hello World custom module tutorial in drupal 8, and ive gotten the biggest error ive ever seen, and i have no idea how to debug it, the error happens inside of drupal/admin/structure/block when i try to apply my hello world block to the header.

```
   Uncaught AjaxError: 
   An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
   HTTP Result Code: 200
  Debugging information follows.
   Path: /drupal/admin/structure/block/add/hello_block/bartik?region=header
   StatusText: OK
   CustomMessage: The response failed verification so will not be processed.
ResponseText: [{"command":"settings","settings":{"ajaxTrustedUrl":{"form_action_cc611e1d":true},"machineName":{"#edit-settings-label--Iv5Pc3nzWIo":{"exists":"\\Drupal\\block\\Entity\\Block::load","replace_pattern":"[^a-z0-9_.]+","source":["settings","label"],"target":"#edit-id--TcX7cq-nUb8","label":"Machine name","replace":"_","standalone":false,"field_prefix":"","field_suffix":"","suffix":"#edit-settings-label--Iv5Pc3nzWIo-machine-name-suffix"}},"langcode":"en","ajaxPageState":   {"theme":"seven","libraries":"block\/drupal.block,block\/drupal.block,bloc k\/drupal.block.admin,block\/drupal.block.admin,block\/drupal.block.admin,
```

And it goes on and on for like 100 lines worth of weird json output.

Now, ive followed another tutorial, which is the other one on the official site called  Lorem Ipsum generator, which works completely fine, and that module has no problems what so ever, so im plan is to eventually have made an exact copy of the loremipsum module and then it would work. But can someone add some rationale as to either how to debug these kind of issues or what this exact issue usually means in a drupal context?

My own best guess is that its permission related somehow, but im logged in as administrator, and i basically have all permissions.